# Is there any phone number representation guaranteed to be unique?

Tags: telephony

I'm aware that lots of local representations of phone numbers clash between countries. i.e. there's no guarantee that a US phone number represented in local conventions (i.e. (401) 555-8675) doesn't clash with a different phone number represented in accordance with its locality.

Is the conventional internationalized format used in the US and europe (i.e. +1 (401) 555-8675) guaranteed to be globally unique if stored as, say, a normalized string ("+14013398675")?

Comment: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md

Comment: To my best reading, this document implies the answer is no. You can coerce most, but not all, phone numbers into the E.164 spec.

The [doc for libphonenumber's formatting classes](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber/8.10.2) describes some standardized formats but suggests storing using the library's PhoneNumber class.
(I don't know if the string representation of that class would be a good candidate for a unique id.)

Comment: "You can coerce most, but not all, phone numbers into the E.164 spec." - Yes, that was my impression as well.